# Leaflet wont work with Vue using browserify

Tags: leaflet, browserify

I'm new using browserify and VueJS. I have a project where I'd like to use the map service Leaflet. So as i show in the code down below I try to require it, I have pulled it in using npm. If I look in the compiled JS file i can find Leaflet there. So that seems to work..

I'll show a image of my resulting map when i try to initialize it in the browser:
[Broken Leaflet map](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nmrhgm4s3cvgi6m/leaflet.png?dl=0)

So as you can see the tiles are behaving really wierd, and nothing works as it should. Draging the map does really strange things..

This is the code for the components JS.

```
var L = require('leaflet');

module.exports = {

data: function () {
    return {
        map: false,
        samples: [],
        messages: [],
        customer_id: '',
        year: ''
    }
},

methods: {

fetch: function (id, year, successHandler) {
    var that = this
    that.$set('customer_id', id)
    that.$set('year', year)
    successHandler(id);
}

},

ready: function () {
    var map = L.map('map').setView([41.3921, 2.1705], 13);

    L.Icon.Default.imagePath = 'images/';

    var osmTiles = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
    var attribution = '© OpenStreetMap contributors';

    L.tileLayer(osmTiles, {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: attribution
    }).addTo(map);

},

route: {
    data: function (transition) {
        this.fetch(this.$route.params.customer_id, this.$route.params.year, function (data) {
            transition.next({customer_id: data})
        })
    }
}}
```

Right now I tried require:ing the leaflet package in my components script file.

Somewhere along the line Leaflet breaks.. I get no errors in the console when viewing the map, but as you can see it doesn't look good.

I would be really happy for all the help i can get!

Edit:
I just tried using chart.js in my project, required in the same way as leaflet, works like a charm.. Can't understand why leaflet wont work.

/ Simon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the Leaflet style sheet. Add it (for the correct version) using a link tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.css" />
```

Comment: Of course, I should have thought of that. Thank you!